# Confusion with how Win32 API calls work in assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I don't know how to ask this better but why does this:

```
call ExitProcess
```

do the same as this?:

```
mov eax, ExitProcess
mov eax, [eax]
call eax
```

I would think that these would be equivalent:

```
call ExitProcess
```

```
mov eax, ExitProcess
call eax
```

Comment: What assembler are you using?  It's probably just silently converting call ExitProcess to call [ExitProcess] to make life a bit easier on the programmer.

Comment: Odd, according to the documentation the square brackets should be mandatory.  Do "call ExitProcess" and "call [ExitProcess]" actually product the same assembly code?

Comment: No they don't call ExitProcess I believe goes to some jmp instruction that then jumps to [ExitProcess] while call [ExitProcess] goes straight there. What about functions I create I shouldn't need brackets around those should I?

Comment: Hudson, though you've already accepted my answer, I've actually gone the extra mile to figure out why you seem to be able to call directly and indirectly. The direct call only seems that way since it's calling code which then does the indirect call. See the update to my answer for the gory details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When importing the code from a DLL, the symbol `ExitProcess` isn't actually the address of the code that exits your process (it's the *address of the address*). So, in that case, you have to dereference it to get the actual code address.

That means that you must use:

```
call [ExitProcess]
```

to call it.

For example, there's some code at [this location](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65224-intro-to-win32-assembly-using-nasm-part-3/) containing the following:

```
;; Note how we use 'AllocConsole' as if it was a variable. 'AllocConsole', to 
;; NASM, means the address of the AllocConsole "variable" ; but since the 
;; pointer to the AllocConsole() Win32 API function is stored in that 
;; variable, we need to call the address from that variable. 
;; So it's "call the code at the address: whatever's at the address
;; AllocConsole" . 
call [AllocConsole]
```

---

However, importing the DLL directly in user code is not the only way to get at the function. I'll explain why you're seeing both ways below.

The "normal" means of calling a DLL function is to mark it `extern` then `import` it from the DLL:

```
extern ExitProcess
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll
:
call [ExitProcess]
```

Because that sets up the symbol to be an *indirect* reference to the code, you need to call it indirectly.

After some searching, it appears there *is* code in the wild that uses the naked form:

```
call ExitProcess
```

From what I can tell, this all seems to use the `alink` linker, which links with the `win32.lib` library file. It's possible that this library provides the stub for calling the *actual* DLL code, something like:

```
import ExitProcessActual kernel32.dll ExitProcess
global ExitProcess

ExitProcess:
    jmp [ExitProcessActual]
```

In `nasm`, this would import the address of `ExitProcess` from the DLL and call it `ExitProcessActual`, keeping in mind that this address is an indirect reference to the code, not the address of the code itself.

It would then export the `ExitProcess` entry point (the one in this LIB file, not the one in the DLL) so that others could use it.

Then someone could simply write:

```
extern ExitProcess
:
call ExitProcess
```

to exit the process - the library would jump to the actual DLL code.

---

In fact, with a little more research, this is *exactly* what's happening. From the `alink.txt` file which comes with the `alink` download:

> A sample import library for Win32 is included as `win32.lib`. All named exports in `Kernel32`, `User32`, `GDI32`, `Shell32`, `ADVAPI32`, `version`, `winmm`, `lz32`, `commdlg` and `commctl` are included.
>
> Use:
>
> `alink -oPE file[.obj] win32.lib`
>
> to include it or specify
>
> `INCLUDELIB "win32"`
>
> in your source file.
>
> This consists of a series of entries for import redirection - `call MessageBoxA`, and it jumps to `[__imp_MessageBoxA]`, which is in the import table.
>
> Thus calls to imports will run faster if `call [__imp_importName]` is used instead of `call importName`.
>
> See `test.asm`, my sample program, which calls up a message box both ways:

```
includelib "win32.lib"
extrn MessageBoxA:near
extrn __imp_MessageBoxA:dword

codeseg

start:
push 0 ; OK button
push offset title1
push offset string1
push 0
call MessageBoxA

push 0 ; OK button
push offset title1
push offset string2
push 0
call large [large __imp_MessageBoxA]
```

(`__imp_MessageBoxA` is the symbol imported from the DLL, equivalent to my `ExitProcessActual` above).

Comment: Is that because it's in the IAT? Also, then why does "call ExitProcess" work?

Comment: Yes, it's because it's in the import table. As to the second part of your comment, I have no idea. I would have thought that _wouldn't_ work unless there's some magic happening due to the way `ExitProcess` is imported or invoked, such as if `ExitProcess` is given the real code target rather than the address in the IAT. I've never used the "naked" version myself.

Comment: And it appears my suspicions were correct. The code that uses the naked form all seems to use win32.lib from `alink`, which provides directly callable functions which in turn indirectly call the DLL entry.